# How to parse [object Object]?

Tags: node.js, object

I try to get data from a valid file and it return [object Object] so I can't get any value from it.

```js
const data = require('./path/to/file');
console.log(data, data.id);
```

Data file

```js
module.exports = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'fox',
  rate: 10
}
```

or json data file

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "fox",
  "rate": 10
}
```

Console:

```
[object Object]
undefined
```

I try to use `JSON.parse(data)` but it still like that

Comment: is this "json" file?

Comment: i try both json and js but it's still like that

Comment: That's just how an object is _displayed_. What _is_ in that file? What makes you think it _should_ have an id property?

Comment: i updated the data file, check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected because you are logging in nodejs console, which behaves differently than browser console. If you wish to be able to log full objects in nodejs console, you can use

```
console.log(JSON.strinfigy(data))
```

check more about it here: https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-log-an-object-in-nodejs

Comment: but how to get value from that object?

Comment: check here on how to read object properties: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp
your `data.id` displaying `undefined` would mean that `id` property does not exist on `data`

Comment: there is id property in my data file

Comment: can you share the output of this `console.log(JSON.strinfigy(data))`

Comment: '{"id":1,"name":"fox","rate":10}' here

Comment: In node.js console, logging objects would look fine for few depths.

Comment: and JSON.parse(data) didn't work?

Comment: JSON.parse(data) it still [object Object] and data.id still undefined

Comment: You need `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and `JSON.parse(data).id`